# Implements keyword in android

Tags: java, android

In Android I am seeing code like this:

```
public class Now extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
```

Is this legal in java? What exactly is View.OnClickListener representing here.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion here. My question is really about the dot notation used in the above code. How can I use View.OnClickListener. I thought we can only use like 'implements View' and nor 'View.OnClickListener'

Comment: You can use either `implements View.OnClickListener` (using `import android.view.*;`) or directly `implements OnCickListener` (using `import android.view.View;`). You don't implement `View` as it is not an `interface`. Check the links I posted to the View class description and source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OnClickListener` is the interface used to receive click events. You need to override the `onClick()` method and implement your own code to deal with it. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html

You can take a look at the `View` class structure here:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#nestedclasses

And browse the implementation here: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/view/View.java

You may want to read the android Dev Guide (specially the topic to handle UI events): http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html

The following two are equivalent:

```
import android.view.View;
public class Now extends ActivityGroup implements OnClickListener {

import android.view.*;
public class Now extends ActivityGroup implements View.OnClickListener {
```

---

The following are not needed after the clarification

And perhaps the Oracle's java interface tutorial:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html

Answer (score 4):

The question seems to be about the use of `View.x`. As @Vicente_Plata nicely put it in the comments:

> OnClickListener is an interface
>   declared inside the View class. Like
>   an "inner class" but, rather, an
>   "inner interface

---

Old answer:

---

View.OnclickListener is an **interface**. It defines methods that your activity must implement, in this case an `OnClickListener()`. Anyone checking wants to know if there is such a function in your class, so they can use `Now` as an `OnclickListener`.

An interface does not provide an implementation.

Also, from [this page](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html)

> Implementing an interface allows a
>   class to become more formal about the
>   behavior it promises to provide.
>   Interfaces form a contract between the
>   class and the outside world, and this
>   contract is enforced at build time by
>   the compiler. If your class claims to
>   implement an interface, all methods
>   defined by that interface must appear
>   in its source code before the class
>   will successfully compile.

Comment: Actually the idea of an interface or an abstract class is to force you to write the desired behavior having a pre-defined method signature (parameters). This way the "System" can call your implementation and be certain that your method accepts those parameters.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion here. My question is really about the dot notation used in the above code. How can I use View.OnClickListener

Comment: Your "actually" implies you disagree with me, but I think you comment goes right with what I just typed, just i slightly different words.

Comment: OnClickListener is an interface declared inside the View class. Like an "inner class" but, rather, an "inner interface" :P . http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html

Comment: @Nanne yeah sorry, I didn't mean to imply that. Just wanted to explain it in another way. "Indeed: the idea of an interface"... =)

Answer (score 0):

As others already pointed out, `implements View.OnClickListener` specifies that your class implements the methods defined in the `View.OnClickListener` interface. If the dot notation makes you uncomfortable, you can import the interface explicitly:

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class Now extends Activity implements OnClickListener
// ...
```