# "implements" keyword in java?

Tags: java

I am new to android development, I have gone through some code and found the following line of code :

```
class Preview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
}
```

Can someone explains or give me a hint to what is really happening here especialy on implements `SurfaceHolder.Callback`?

thanks

Comment: read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769036/implements-keyword-in-android?rq=1

Comment: Android SDK is based on Java, so all you have to do is go find out what the implements keyword means in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a class `implements` an interface, it means that instances of that class (`Preview`, in your case) are forced to contain definitions for the methods that the interface (`SurfaceHolder.Callback`) exposes.

It also means that you can use any expression that returns an instance of your class (`Preview`) or its subclasses wherever an expression of the interface type (`SurfaceHolder.Callback`) is required.

Answer (score 1):

In Java `implements SurfaceHolder.Callback` means you are implementing `"Interface"`  `SurfaceHolder.Callback`.If you implement interface means you have to define all methods inside interface `SurfaceHolder.Callback`.It wil automatically ask you to implement `"ALL abstract method"`.

Answer (score 1):

The "implements" key word in Java requires that the class being defined also include declarations and definitions of all the method signitures defined in the specified Interface class.

In the example provided, SurfaceHolder.Callback is an Interface and declares some set of methods.  Thus, the new class, Preview, by definition, also declares those same methods.  In most cases, the methods are already defined as part of the Interface class, but not necessarily so.  The programmer can override these methods as they see fit, but users of the Preview class, without knowing anything else, can write more generic and reuseable code by simply referring to, or interacting with, their objects as SurfaceHolder.Callback objects.